# Can a gem binary bring its own tab completion?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, rubygems

I developed a gem that includes an executable script ([application file](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#bindir) in rubygems terms). When invoking, I'd like to complete filenames in a given directory (which is not the current working dir), like so:

```
foo edit my<tab>
```

gets expanded to:

```
foo edit myfile
```

What I could do is include a script that installs shell completions. If that's the only solution—fine. But I was wondering if there's a way I can free users from the additional step and include completions in my gem directly.

So: Is there a way for a gem to bring its own tab completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are typing the command to start your script, your script isn't running yet. It can't intervene in the processing of its own arguments while they are still being typed. If possible, you can have the `gem` file install a bash completion file and modify the user's `~/.bashrc` file to load them as part of the installation process.

Comment: I know :( I was hoping to get around that "installation process" -- be it a convention ("put your completions here and they will be used automagically") or something else...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Ruby's [Abbrev](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/abbrev/rdoc/Abbrev.html) module. (About.com also has some [useful information](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/ss/Calculating-Abbreviations.htm).)

From the docs:

```
Calculate the set of unique abbreviations for a given set of strings.

require 'abbrev'
require 'pp'

pp Abbrev::abbrev(['ruby', 'rules']).sort
Generates:

[["rub", "ruby"],
 ["ruby", "ruby"],
 ["rul", "rules"],
 ["rule", "rules"],
 ["rules", "rules"]]
Also adds an abbrev method to class Array.
```

I'd read the directory, pass the files and subdirectories to Abbrev, and convert the result into a hash. Watch as the user types. If they press <kbd>Tab</kbd> see if what they typed matches a key in the hash. If it does what they typed is unique and can be resolved to the value of that element.

This is how to turn the output of Abbrev into a hash:

```
irb(main):009:0> hash = Hash[%w[ruby rules].abbrev]
=> {"rub"=>"ruby", "rule"=>"rules", "rul"=>"rules", "ruby"=>"ruby", "rules"=>"rules"}
```

Comment: I guess I did not state my question clearly enough: I don't want to use tab completion programmatically, I just want to somehow "bundle" a completion script for the shell when invoking my script. Or did I read your answer wrong?

Comment: You weren't clear. The gem is the Ruby code, plus a little bit of extra metadata to let it get installed correctly. Shell autocompletion depends on the shell the user runs; I use BASH and autocompletion works on all files/folders passed to all executables. Ruby scripts I write have it automatically because of the shell. The shell can be told about commands inside the script but I wouldn't want a gem messing with that, that's for me, the user, to do.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's questionable for a gem to fiddle with the user shell. I guess the best thing to do is dump the completion script on the shell so the user can copy it...

Comment: I disagree with the Tin Man.  I would be totally fine with a gem adding its own tab completion if it would add functionality that I wanted.  For instance I am working with a gem called gemr.  It will return the most up to date version of a gem from rubygems.org.  I am trying to make it so when you tab the auto completion helps you complete against a list of available gems at ruby gems.  That would be more helpful than the bash autocompletion.  I cannot think of a scenario where I would type `gemr` first and try to use the standard bash autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) has come to the correct conclusion that installation is inevitable, I would suggest taking a look at how some other projects have tackled this issue.

---

The Travis CI *travis* gem offers to install completions at first execution. It saves the completion script to *~/.travis/travis.sh* then appends the following to *.bashrc*:

```
# added by travis gem
[ -f ~/.travis/travis.sh ] && source ~/.travis/travis.sh
```

---

The previous example is somewhat invasive. For a more laissez-faire approach, see Python's `pip` (similar to Ruby's `gem`). It has a hidden completion option that prints a bash or zsh completion script to stdout. It is up to the user to decide how to source it.

`pip completion --bash` outputs the following:

```
# pip bash completion start
_pip_completion()
{
    COMPREPLY=( $( COMP_WORDS="${COMP_WORDS[*]}" \
                   COMP_CWORD=$COMP_CWORD \
                   PIP_AUTO_COMPLETE=1 $1 ) )
}
complete -o default -F _pip_completion pip
# pip bash completion end
```

On a somewhat different, but related note... If you look at the aforementioned completion script, you'll notice it does something rather peculiar. Rather than use a static list of completions (which must be updated frequently and is prone to inaccuracy) or generate the completions dynamically by parsing help messages (often unacceptably slow) it uses a third option. It passes the command-line state directly in `pip` so as to have it generate the completions.

---

Perhaps the most relevant, but also the grandest approach would be to create a global completion script for Ruby gems. The user simply has to install the one global completion gem (there is no getting around this) and then completions are immediately available for any other gems. As far as I know, no one has implemented this in Ruby. For a Python implementation, see [argcomplete](https://argcomplete.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#activating-global-completion).

Installation is as follows:

```
pip install argcomplete
activate-global-python-argcomplete --dest=/path/to/bash_completion.d
```

Scripts are easily adapted. It is then essentially a one-liner to pass your parser object to argcomplete.